# jquery sortable with php and mysql

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

Have two connected sortable lists inside a div.Need to be able to reorder items in each list,updating with ajax.And I want to use it with php and mysql.but I don't know how to do it? could anyone can help me? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article might just be of help. I am using the example provided from the article with modifications for my website.

The jQuery Sortable Lists with Drag and Drop handling:
http://www.wil-linssen.com/jquery-sortable-lists-with-drag-drop-handle/
Extending the Sortable List to add AJAX and MySQL
http://www.wil-linssen.com/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

Comment: 3KS!
but i wanna sort one element from one div to another,not in one div.
how to update the received element in the new div?

Comment: sorry then i don't have a solution for that.